# Is there a global enable/disable to a MySQL row?

Tags: mysql

Let's say all of my tables have a column named 'enabled', which only contains 0 or 1. To use the enable column, I would have to add 'WHERE enabled = 1' in every single SQL query to skip the 'disabled' rows. Is there any ways that I could perform this without tediously adding a WHERE clause in all my SQL queries, i.e. a global enable/disable to a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [View](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) with the condition:

```sql
 CREATE VIEW ViewMyTableOnlyEnabled AS SELECT Field1, ..., FieldN FROM myTable WHERE enabled <> 0;
```

and use it like a table:

```sql
SELECT Field1, ..., FieldN FROM ViewMyTableOnlyEnabled;
```

I changed the criteria to `WHERE enabled <> 0` as False is usually stored as 0, but True is sometimes stored as -1

Answer (score 2):

No. [obligatory extra characters]

Answer (score 0):

The only other way is to move it to a different table.

When adding `enabled` type of fields make sure they are added to the indexes most commonly when used in queries.